# Working w/ Custom View Template

Tags: views, theming

I'm cutting my teeth on custom view templates.. specifically:

views-view-table--MYNEWVIEW.tpl.php

I've copied the default template code into this file. When it's looping through the rows, building the table cells, I'm not sure how to tell which field I'm on to be able to put that single field on a new row.

Here's a link to what I'm trying to accomplish.

[Views - Custom Field Layout?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149618/views-custom-field-layout)

Obviously, I'm not very knowledgeable yet on modifying view templates, so I'm hoping someone could direct me to resources/examples of working with the various variables available. I've enabled the Devel module and have sprinkled  snippets around, but I'm not grasping how I would tell which field is current in the foreach loop.

Thanks. Bill